How can I restrict the number of matches in reclin2?
I am working on an record linkage issue and use the package reclin2.
Within each block I compare all records with each other and want to link the records using one of the functions select_greedy or select_n_to_m or select_unique.
However, when linking the records there are some records which are linked to another record more than once, which ís not possible in real world in my use case.
For example, for BLOCK_ID 15, record 25 is linkes to record 26, record 27 is linked to record 28 and record 28 is linked to 29 - so the number of links between records is too high, record 28 is linked twice, which is not possible
Linking data depends on the attribute "MATCH_PROB_LOG_AGG_SIM" and the result of applying the select_greedy function is attribute "LABEL_LOG_AGG_SIM_GREEDY_APPROACH". The code for linking the records is:
dt_check_so <- 
  reclin2::select_greedy(pairs = dt_check_so, 
                         variable = "LABEL_LOG_AGG_SIM_GREEDY_APPROACH", 
                         score = "MATCH_PROB_LOG_AGG_SIM",
                         threshold = 0.5, 
                         m = 1, n = 1)

The pairs data I am using is the following:
structure(list(BLOCK_ID = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109),
.x = c(24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 31, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 155, 155, 155, 155, 155, 156, 156, 156, 156, 157, 157, 157, 158, 158, 159),
.y = c(25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 29, 30, 31, 32, 30, 31, 32, 31, 32, 32, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 157, 158, 159, 160, 158, 159, 160, 159, 160, 160), 
MATCH_PROB_LOG_AGG_SIM = c(0.000428601580156999, 0.0222900494659686, 0.021491440074508, 0.000415661410975634, 0.0184481392177389, 0.000169658014105288, 0.000168244368541897, 0.00671997220801128, 0.943223731728283, 0.940192742061438, 0.229375788610937, 0.839766566216083, 0.00104291922793942, 0.000991895947366173, 0.0158261836599051, 0.233531445137857, 0.940555782629002, 0.0922206104175528, 0.0525899642660352, 0.0501436655256163, 0.000311528231221161, 0.943574374825607, 0.0913873887164412, 0.0507621305532629, 0.048396512863072, 0.000329113117918, 0.839302726492757, 0.00101145059126253, 0.000961965384645035, 0.0170922393434041, 0.0739464330605281, 0.0700337095085684, 0.000380598561193863, 0.211991370240017, 0.206051649540572, 0.220984320458671, 0.456534621652727, 0.457531306881546, 0.443935557752046, 0.246309538106261, 0.00596626012201531, 0.00601799556027603, 0.232187647977181, 0.23213679440944, 0.232145946380941, 0.00587914403764306, 0.0297811942507514, 0.000532411813693522, 0.199827228108601, 0.189060001777758, 0.051994759032846, 0.733343105021757, 0.735983905376286, 0.0478703652873168, 0.0478500899160425, 0.0478537384434482, 0.75313038857821, 0.00150894402748969, 0.0737431434986302, 0.23472857305074, 0.06241052042164, 0.779390017353154, 0.78178981774343, 0.0605776347159034, 0.0605514513831739, 0.0605561630366954, 0.772154161537033, 0.00157551758907047, 0.0670775091805445, 0.0627444756244101, 0.780301652848927, 0.782720059994026, 0.0642589286322424, 0.0642309639616452, 0.0642359961624293, 0.778126815963358, 0.00159784424435803, 0.0662305858586334, 0.942623957372634, 0.943559979458906, 0.230026078159729, 0.229924641689411, 0.229942895749887, 0.94202544736342, 0.00301046604655214, 0.12285309032845, 0.244524786870112, 0.94260238231416, 0.94257122917432, 0.9425768372388, 0.237615255328617, 0.137503528313104, 0.00261432179002524, 0.941655833625, 0.941624338052205, 0.941630007752361, 0.2371905890208, 0.136652951540503, 0.00259547610333825, 0.247654999033701, 0.24767440309935, 0.941163519727298, 0.00306034754004773, 0.118665177080607, 0.247743414191147, 0.941131695331207, 0.00306107892308057, 0.118690466493947, 0.941137424226401, 0.00306094726127589, 0.118685914055388, 0.137134399941411, 0.00287333426504944, 0.931341825168703),
LABEL_LOG_AGG_SIM_GREEDY_APPROACH = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)), 
class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 114L))

There are much more blocks in which records are compared.
Also for functions select_n_to_m and select_unique the result is not as I would expect.
I understand, that I can force the number of links to be restricted using the parameters n = 1 and m = 1, however that does not work apparently.
Any ideas how to solve this issue are welcome.
Thanks,
Marius
